# Why do all devices discovered by CBCentralmanager have name=null?

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am attempting to detect battery levels for connected BT devices on macOS. While I can get CBCentralManager to detect SOME nearby devices, all of the devices it detects are name=Null, even though there are numerous devices that should be detected and should have names (e.g., AirPods, magic trackpad, magic keyboard, etc).

My BT Manager class is:

```swift
import Cocoa
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var centralManager = CBCentralManager()
    var peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()
    var discoveredPeripherals:[CBPeripheral]?
    var selectedPeripheral:CBPeripheral?

    let queue = DispatchQueue.main


    let batteryLevelService = [CBUUID(string: "0x2A19")]

    override init() {
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: queue)
        super.init()
        centralManager.delegate = self
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOff:
            print("BLE is powered off")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("BLE is powered on")
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        case .resetting:
            print("BLE is resetting")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("BLE is not authorized")
        case .unknown:
            print("BLE state is unknown")
        case .unsupported:
            print("BLE is unsupported")
        default:
            print("Unable to determine BLE state")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        // Code Here
    }
}
```

I assign that class to an object in my main ViewController class.

I would normally have expected the console to show nearby discoverable devices as well as already-connected devices. However, all I get is:

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x600003508b00, identifier = C9A74282-A40C-46C1-9C2F-9646D2BCE8B5, name = (null), state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x600003500840, identifier = 1EF2CD7F-8FAA-4510-A7DB-B4E060B2378B, name = (null), state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x600003500a50, identifier = 1EF2CD7F-8FAA-4510-A7DB-B4E060B2378B, name = (null), state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x600003508b00, identifier = BA372C81-993F-436D-994E-B31BDAB47BC7, name = (null), state = disconnected>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all devices advertise their name. There is very little space in an advertising packet (~30 bytes), and the name may not fit if there are other more-important things to advertise. A single custom service can use up 16 bytes. You may not be able to determine the name without connecting. Even then, the device may not have a BLE name.

> I would normally have expected the console to show nearby discoverable devices as well as already-connected devices.

I'm not sure why you expect that. `scanForPeripherals` returns information about devices that are advertising. It is very common for a device to stop advertising when it's connected to (it's common for devices to only support a single connection). If you want to see connected devices, call `retrieveConnectedPeripherals`.

Comment: Good point. I replaced the scanForPeripherals call to `centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: batteryLevelService)` where `batteryLevelService` = `[CBUUID(string: "0x2A19")]` and it returns nothing...

Comment: Is there a device BLE-connected that includes the battery level service? How are you determining that?

Comment: Wait… 2A19 isn't the Battery Service; that's the Battery Level characteristic. The Battery Level service is 180F.

Comment: I had connected bluetooth headphones (AirPods), which should, in theory be returned as a peripheral, no? I'll add 0x180f to the array to broaden the criteria. (I'm still wrapping my head around the CBUUIDs!)

Comment: What do you mean by "connected?" Audio connections have nothing at all to do with BLE connections. The two are both called "Bluetooth" but have almost nothing else in common.

Comment: I meant paired+connected (in the user-facing/Bluetooth sys prefs. Sense). I am seeing that my initial question is clearly not even in the ballpark, I’ve got more to learn about CoreBluetooth obviously! Thanks for your help getting me here.