# MacOS: BLE scanning always return nil as peripheral.name

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am scanning BLE devices on MacOS. I am using the following code:

```
final class BLERepository: NSObject {
  private var _centralManager: CBCentralManager!

  override init() {
    self._centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil)
    super.init()
    self._centralManager.delegate = self
  }
}

extension BLERepository: CBPeripheralDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
      _centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
    default:
      break
    }
  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("\(peripheral.name)")
  }
}
```

Peripheral name is always nil. But as I understood `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true` should solve this issue and duplicates are coming to me but the name never became valid.
I tried to use Xcode Bluetooth tool or some other scanners and all of them get the name of devices around me.

Comment: Have you tried extract the name from the advertising data instead? That should be more consistent.

Comment: I tried to `for ad in advertisementData { print("AD Data: \(ad)") }` - nothing ((

Comment: It is completely normal for BLE devices to not include a name in their advertising packets. Space there is very limited, and names can be too long to fit. Do you have reason to believe that these devices are advertising a name? (That's not the same thing as having a name.) What do you see with BLE scanners such as LightBlue or BlueSee?

Comment: Yes. I mention this in the original question - third-party scanners on different devices get the names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do all devices discovered by CBCentralmanager have name=null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834868/why-do-all-devices-discovered-by-cbcentralmanager-have-name-null)